# generating jquery plugin with multiple plugin calls and different settings

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, jquery-plugins

i made a jQuery plugin like so

```
(function($){
    $.fn.pluginname = function(options) {
        if (!this.length) { return this; }
        var settings = $.extend(true, {}, $.fn.pluginname.default, options);
        $w=$(this);
        $w.bind("click", function(e){
          e.preventDefault();
          var elm = e.target;
          elm.css({top : "+=100%"});
          elm.attr({settings.examplePre : settings.exampleInt});
        });
        return this;
    };
    $.fn.pluginname.default = {
        examplePre:"data-object",
        exampleInt: 1e3
    };
})(window.jQuery);
```

this whould apply the fn.function once to the selected elements

so if called twice, like..

```
$(document)ready(function(){
    $(".selector").pluginname({
       examplePre: "data-first"
    });
    $(".secondselector").pluginname({
       examplePre:"data-second",
       exampleInt: 10
    });
});
```

the second plugin call overwrites the first one.
i read and tryed but none of my plugin layouts worked. 
how to change this layout so that settings from `.selector` and `.secondselector` got its own data preset, even when called twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to scope the settings variable, so it's not affected from the outside.

```
$.fn.pluginname = function(options) {
  return this.each(function () {
    var settings = $.extend(true, {}, $.fn.pluginname.default, options);
    $w = $(this);
    $w.bind("click", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(this).css("top", "+=100%");
      $(this).attr(settings.examplePre, settings.exampleInt);
    });
  });
};
```

Here is a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WxSW6/)

Comment: thanks for the hint, got it to work. my problem was that didnt find a way to place the setting to each set of selectors which where grouped.
even funny, the created wrap doesnt have to be unique to hold its setting. see http://jsfiddle.net/wAgq2/2/